# Rotate shapes using Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

When I add the function `g2d.rotate(some Number)` the screen shows no shape at all, and without this function everything is working.

What is the problem?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setColor(color);
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xCordinate,yCordinate,4);

   // g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
    g2d.draw(polygon);
    g2d.fill(polygon);
}
```

and in the main:

```
public class Main extends JPanel {
    Camera c=new Camera(100, 50, (Math.PI)*2, 0, 150,200,Math.PI,Color.MAGENTA);
    //Camera c1=new Camera(100, 50, (Math.PI)*2, 0, 150,200,0,Color.black);
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setSize(400, 400);
      f.add(new Main());
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      //c1.paintComponent(g);
      c.paintComponent(g);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code has several problems:

1. Do not override paint(). You should never invoke paintComponent() directly. You just add the component to a panel and it will be painted automatically. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.
2. Your Polygon doesn't have any points. You need to add 4 points to it.
3. When you rotate a Shape you also need to translate it.

Check out [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) and [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/). The source code shows you how to do rotation or you can just use the classes as is.